# Get the first 3 elements for each value of an attribute SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the mondial database that can be queried here http://www.semwebtech.org/sqlfrontend/

---

I am trying to get the 3 religion that are most praticed on each continent I've come up with this:

`select religion.name, sum(religion.percentage) as total, continent 
 from religion join encompasses on religion.country = encompasses.country 
 group by name, continent order by continent, total DESC`

This gives me a list of each religion with for each continent ordered by their popularity but how do I get the first 3 results for each continent ?

I have looked up cursor but I don't see how to apply them to my case and it looks like there is a simple answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select rc.*
from (select r.name, sum(r.percentage) as total, e.continent,
             row_number() over (partition by e.continent order by sum(r.percentage) as total desc) as seqnum
      from religion r join
           encompasses e
           on r.country = e.country 
      group by r.name, e.continent
     ) rc
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Having explained how to modify your query to answer the question, let me now point out that your query is wrong.  The sum of the percentage of people is not the same as the total number of people.  For instance, I think Bhutan is pretty close to 100% Buddhist (Buddhism is the state religion).  But there are more Buddhists in India (~0.7% Buddhist, according to one source).

Comment: Yes I didn't take into account the population of each country into account, I though that it will not output drastic differences, I might be wrong I will look it up